# Laravel 5.2 - PHP 7.0.6 coalesce operators returning empty strings

Tags: php, laravel, null-coalescing-operator

So I have a project that relies on Laravel 5.2 / PHP 7.0.6 and it uses Transformers to deal with API responses. In MANY places in our code we use the new php 7 coalescing (??) operators. However, since our update to php 7.0.6 we are seeing a lot of the following:

Code: `'vip_id' => $beneficiaryQdro->beneficiary->vip_id ?? ''`

**Expected Result**: 11583 (the vip id of the beneficiary relationship)

**Actual Result**: ''

I have tried running this: `dd($beneficiaryQdro->beneficiary->vip_id)` and I get the proper vip_id returned. However, when I add on the coalescing operator it once again returns an empty string. This WAS working before. Anyone else seen this happen with the new php release?

**Update**: I have fixed it by eager loading the relationship. Something about the coalesce operator doesn't like dealing with a relationship where it fills in the information on the fly. I'm not sure who's issue this becomes. Before 7.0.6 coalescing operators were dealing with relationships that weren't eager loaded just fine but this update broke it somehow.

Comment: [No obvious problems or change in behaviour](https://3v4l.org/muSOD)

Comment: Actually I don't know what the problem is but how I have fixed it is by eager loading the relationship. Something about the coalesce operator doesn't like dealing with a relationship where it fills in the information on the fly. Using a basic php object can't possibly replicate this issue.

Comment: You could try do set a variable first like `$vip_id =$beneficiaryQdro->beneficiary->vip_id`.

Comment: Id rather eager load or lazy eager load. I've already fixed it. However, I AM curious as to why this is just happening now. 7.0.5 does not have this issue. I wouldn't mind putting in a bug on either PHP or Laravel but im honestly not sure who would need to handle this

Comment: I'd suggest reporting it to them both. They probably both need to be made aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing:

```
$beneficiaryQdro->beneficiary->vip_id ?? ''
```

is the same as doing:

```
isset($beneficiaryQdro->beneficiary->vip_id) ? $beneficiaryQdro->beneficiary->vip_id : ''
```

So unless the `beneficiary` relationship is loaded this will always be false when doing isset and result in being ''.

There are 2 bugs fixed in PHP 7.0.6 that look like they relate to the behaviour you had and the issue you're having:

**Coalescing operator on classes with overridden __get() method**

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71359

**Null coalescing operator and ArrayAccess**

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71731

So it could be an issue with how Eloquent is handling it with its magic methods. I don't have an install under PHP 7 to confirm this though.

Looks like this was also asked here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-relation-isset-always-return-false

It looks like it shouldn't have worked pre 7.0.6.

So to summarize, isset doesn't load relationships.

Comment: I disagree that this would always be the case because it was never the case till this version

Comment: I meant as my understanding of the coalesce operator it should always be false.

Comment: not true. Laravel relationships are loaded on the fly when called and the coalesce operator USED to let them run and then check the response (proper order of operations) but now it just checks it immediately and doesn't wait which causes it to always return the default

Comment: Did bit more research for you. Updated my answer.